# Tracking of vehicles in Rails via geocoding and plotting on a map

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gps, geolocation, geocoding

I have a Rails 3.2.19 app that I'd like to track vehicles (Units) with using geocoding and plotting on Google Maps.

I came up with a way to get coordinates by using the `taip_parser` gem and creating a rake task that constantly listens for inbound taip data, parses the latitude and longitude and updates the vehicle model's `latitude` and `longitude` fields.  From there I was able to plot vehicle locations using the `gmaps4rails` gem.  The limitation of this is that you have to use a specific 3G/4G modem that speaks in TAIP to send the lat/long to the Rails server so the rake task can parse it.

What I'd like to do is to negate having to use these expensive 3G/4G modems and instead pull the coordinates from a mobile device located in the vehicle (currently an iPad).

So my thoughts are to use the HTML5 Geolocation feature in the browser to obtain the latitude and longitude of the unit and somehow store that into the Unit's latitude/longitude database fields upon page/partial refresh which happens currently via Ajax.

This would break the dependence on the the existing devices and allow any mobile GPS enabled device to be compatible with this feature.

Currently in my app I have `gmaps4rails` to plot the units using my rake task and taip data parsing and also `geocoder` which I'm testing to geocode addresses as they are created for another purpose.

My questions are:

Can someone provide an example of how to use the HTML5 geolocation feature in a rails view?  Once HTML5 geolocation is enabled in the view, how to get the latitude and longitude into the respective models latitude and longitude fields?  Perhaps an example iteration of multiple objects' latitude longitude using gmaps4rails

If my question is too vague or convoluted please let me know so I can edit it and make things more clear as to what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working by using some ajax and a custom controller action in my Rails app.  Using Ajax and a hidden form, I pull the coordinates using HTML5, populate the form with the values, and to an ajax post submit.

See below for the code:

**controller**

```
  def update_gps
    @unit = current_user.unit
    if @unit.update_attributes(params[:unit])
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html {redirect_to mdt_path}
        format.js { render "index"}
      end
    end
  end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
 <div class="hidden">
    <%= form_for(@unit, :url => update_gps_mdt_index_path, :html => {:method => :post}) do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :latitude %>
    <%= f.text_field :longitude %>
    <%= f.button :submit %>
    <% end %>
    </div>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        setInterval(function(){
          $.getScript("/mdt");
        }, 10000);
      });

    function updateCurrentLocation(){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      var c = position.coords
      var location = c.latitude +", "+ c.longitude
      console.log(location)
      var $updateLocationForm = $(".edit_unit")
      $("#unit_latitude").val(c.latitude)
      $("#unit_longitude").val( c.longitude)
      var data = $(".edit_unit").serialize();
    console.log(data)
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: $(".edit_unit").attr("action"),
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
    console.log('working: '+data);
    },
    error: function(msg) {
    console.log('not working '+msg);
    }
    });
    });
    }
    setInterval(updateCurrentLocation, 10000)
    </script>
```

Comment: Good work! I am attempting somthing very similar myself and really confused about the whole thing! How are you updating the map to show the position?

Comment: @AlexHickinbotham The map gets updated via a simple ajax/JS calls every 40 seconds.  I'm using Gmaps4rails to plot the vehicles on a map after rendering to JSON.  Once the map reloads via ajax you can see the vehicles move.  It's not exactly realtime but it's close enough.  Do you need some help?  I'd be happy to help you work on this.